# python, 2 line string to 2 dimension array conversion

Tags: python, arrays, list

```
import numpy as np

text = '''1, 3, 5, 7, 9
          8, 6, 4, 2, 0'''

data = []
```

`\n` exists in after 9

I want an output like this

```
data = [[1,3,5,7,9],[8,6,4,2,0]]
```

numbers in data is int, that converted into int from string

Answer (score 0):

For easy input into numpy use `io.StringIO`

```
>>> from io import StringIO
>>> np.array(StringIO(text).read())
[[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
 [8, 6, 4, 2, 0]]
```

You can use `ast.literal_eval`

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> [list(literal_eval(s)) for s in text.split('\n')]
[[1, 3, 5, 7, 9], [8, 6, 4, 2, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension with `splitlines` and `split`:

```py
text = '''1, 3, 5, 7, 9
          8, 6, 4, 2, 0'''

data = [[int(x) for x in line.split(', ')] for line in text.splitlines()]
print(data) # [[1, 3, 5, 7, 9], [8, 6, 4, 2, 0]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!!! I was looking for this answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `map()` to do this

```
text = '''1, 3, 5, 7, 9
          8, 6, 4, 2, 0'''
lst = list(map(int, text.replace(",","").split()))
print([lst[:5],lst[5:]])
```